# PATCH in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to patch a object with the following code.

```
public object Patch(EditBlog request)
{
     using (var db = _db.Open())
     {
         try
         {
            request.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            Db.Update<Blog>(request, x => x.Id == request.Id);
            return new BlogResponse { Blog = Blog = Db.Select<Blog>(X=>X.Id == request.Id).SingleOrDefault()};
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {

             return HttpError.Conflict("Something went wrong");
         }
     }
 }
```

In Postman, I am calling the function like this "api/blog/1?=Title=Test1&Summary=Test&UserId=1". 
When debugging I can see that those values has been assigned to the request. 
During the Update it throws: "Cannot update identity column 'Id'"

My model looks like this

```
public class Blog
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IUserAuth User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string CompleteText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

And the EditBlog DTO looks like this:

```
[Route("/api/blog/{id}", "PATCH")]
public class EditBlog : IReturn<BlogResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IUserAuth User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string CompleteText { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "Cannot update identity column 'Id'" does not exist anywhere in [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), it could be an error returned by the RDBMS when you're trying to update the Primary Key which OrmLite wouldn't do when updating a Model annotated with a Primary Key like your `Blog` class has with its annotated `[AutoIncrement]` Id Primary Key.

The error is within your `Db.Up<T>` method that's performing the update, which is not an OrmLite API, so it's likely your own custom extension method or an alternative library.

I would implement a PATCH Request in OrmLite with something like:

```
var blog = request.ConvertTo<Blog>();
blog.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
Db.UpdateNonDefaults(blog);
```

i.e. using OrmLite's [UpdateNonDefaults](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#update) API to only update non default fields and updating using the `Blog` Table POCO not the `EditBlog` Request DTO.

Also you should use the [Single APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#select-apis) when fetching a single record, e.g:

```
Blog = Db.SingleById<Blog>(request.Id)
```

or

```
Blog = Db.Single<Blog>(x => x.Id == request.Id)
```

Instead of:

```
Blog = Db.Select<Blog>(X=>X.Id == request.Id).SingleOrDefault()
```

Comment: The 'Db' object is a instance of IDbConnectionFactory, which is registered as       container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
          new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(appSettings.GetString("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"), SqlServerDialect.Provider));
Does this mean that since I use a SQL database, I cannot use the methods from OrmLite?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen I know that `Db` is an ADO.NET `IDbConnection` (resolved from OrmLiteConnectionFactory) but `Db.Up` is not an OrmLite API, whatever it is, it's causing the Error.

Comment: Oh, that is a typo. I am using db.update. Updating the question.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen Please refer to the implementation in my answer. Use your `Blog` data model to update the entity and you should use `UpdateNonDefaults` in PATCH requests.

Comment: Yeah, It works now. When I followed your example in https://docs.servicestack.net/api-design. You did not convert the DTO back to the model (also the reason I used Update) However, the solution provided above works as expected. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen thx for pointing it out in the docs, I've updated it with the correct example.